# How to customize error message and empty data message for SSRM

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image]

Scanning through the documentation, I can't find a way to customize the message. NoRowsOverlay doesn't work in SSRM I believe.

I can go down with hacky way which is call success callback (even it failed) and set error message for single row, but I want to find a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old but if anyone ever faced with the same issue: you can specify `loadingError` in [localisation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/localisation/)

or create your own [Custom Loading Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-loading-cell-renderer/#example-custom-loading-cell-renderer) and check if `node.failedLoad` is `true` render the custom html